# gevent: downside to spawning large number of greenlets?

Tags: python, limit, gevent, spawning

Following on from my question in the comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16433061/348501) to the question ["Gevent pool with nested web requests"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15322701/348501):

Assuming one has a large number of tasks, is there any downside to using gevent.spawn(...) to spawn all of them simultaneously rather than using a gevent pool and pool.spawn(...) to limit the number of concurrent greenlets?

Formulated differently: is there any advantage to "limiting concurrency" with a gevent.Pool even if not required by the problem to be solved?

Any idea what would constitute a "large number" for this issue?

Comment: When not using pool to spawn a large number of greenlets, my program kept alternating between two errors:`gevent.hub.LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever',` and `Gevent <urlopen error [Errno 2] _ssl.c:504: The operation did not complete (read)>`. Everything resolved after I found out an optimal pool size by trial and error. Still irrational to me, but will note it as an advantage of limiting concurrency.  Also, I measured overall time taken to be lower with `pool.spawn()` as opposed to `gevent.spawn()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's just cleaner and a good practice when dealing with a lot of stuff. I ran into this a few weeks ago I was using gevent spawn to verify a bunch of emails against DNS on the order of 30k :).

```
from gevent.pool import Pool
import logging
rows = [ ... a large list of stuff ...]
CONCURRENCY = 200 # run 200 greenlets at once or whatever you want
pool = Pool(CONCURRENCY)
count = 0

def do_work_function(param1,param2):
   print param1 + param2

for row in rows:
  count += 1 # for logging purposes to track progress
  logging.info(count)
  pool.spawn(do_work_function,param1,param2) # blocks here when pool size == CONCURRENCY

pool.join() #blocks here until the last 200 are complete
```

I found in my testing that when CONCURRENCY was around 200 is when my machine load would hover around 1 on a EC2 m1.small. I did it a little naively though, if I were to do it again I'd run multiple pools and sleep some time in between them to try to distribute the load on the NIC and CPU more evenly.

One last thing to keep in mind is keeping an eye on your open files and increasing that if need be: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files. The greenlets I was running were taking up around 5 file descriptors per greenlet so you can run out pretty quickly if you aren't careful. This may not be helpful if your system load is above one as you'll start seeing diminishing returns regardless.

Answer (score 12):

Came here from Google and decided to run a few quick tests to spawn increasing `N` greenlets. Sharing the results as they might be useful to fellow searchers:

```
# 1 greenlet
real    0m1.032s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.009s

# 100 greenlets
real    0m1.037s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.010s

# 1,000 greenlets
real    0m1.045s
user    0m0.035s
sys     0m0.013s

# 10,000 greenlets
real    0m1.232s
user    0m0.265s
sys     0m0.059s

# 100,000 greenlets
real    0m3.992s
user    0m3.201s
sys     0m0.444s
```

So up to 1,000 greenlets and the performance loss is tiny, but once you start hitting 10,000+ greenlets, everything slows down.

Test code:

```
import gevent

N = 0

def test():
    gevent.sleep(1)

while N < 1000:
  N += 1
  gevent.spawn(test)

gevent.wait()
```

Comment: thank you, I needed this information, too. However, on a hunch I decided to run a variation of your test having it sleep for 60 seconds. There was no cpu consumption during the sleep, only during the startup and teardown of greenlets. Launching 100,000 greenlets is actually executing quite a bit of code but it looks like greenlet does not waste any cpu cycles holding onto sleeping greenlets.